# 2 Hyper-V VMs in separate Hosts connected to each other through secondary NICs on each host

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

So, I have two host servers each with an integrated NIC and then another 4-port NIC. Host A is running the primary copy of a VM and host B is running its redundant copy.  the redundancy is done at the application level and requires that the servers have a dedicated connection between each other, no switches, just a crossover cable.  how would I configure my Hyper-V VMs to simulate that direct connection?

If you need any additional detail I will be monitoring the thread closely to make updates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> requires that the servers have a dedicated connection between each other,

I guarantee that is not the case. They may need secondary NIC's, but they can be virtual. I mean, seriously, I run multiple clusters over dual 100g NIC and - the VM's all only have ne NIC each as sstandard.

> how would I configure my Hyper-V VMs to simulate that direct connection?

- Put a second NIC in every VM (virtual NIC)
- Possibly put them on a VLAN number to isolate them
- Set up network betweem them as normal.

Unless the app is VERY well written - with virtualization in mind - it will just check that you talk of a 2nd NIC on the VM OS level. It has NO way of knowing how this maps to a physical NIC, especially not if you set up a VLAN id so it can not reach the first NIC.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

Create a new virtual switch on each Hyper-V host using one of the 4 ports of the 4 port NIC.

Connect this port on each Hyper-V host to the corresponding port on the other Hyper-V host.

Configure each VM with a NIC bound to the this new virtual switch.

**Of course, TomTom is correct in that you probably don't need to do anything special to make this work. You could simply connect the VM's to your network like you would any other host. My answer addresses creating a dedicated physical and virtual connection between these VM's if that's what you really need to do... which you probably don't.**

Comment: and it doesnt matter to use a switch or Crossover cable, i would do the same use on both side a port of the 4 and connect them to ewch other

Comment: The reason yo udo not need a separate connection is that your connection should already be multi port redundant otherwise your cluster is on hobby level and WILL fail anyway. If you set up a half competent solution, your NIC will be a multi port. If you use a real Hyper-V cluster with cluster shared storage that is even mandatory for certification. So, your separate line is acutally LESS (!) protected than the already redundant main line (anmd yes, those can even use redundant switches).